# Is there a way to get and display the file size of all the resources on a website? (img, .css, .js, etc.)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to build a dashboard that can get the file size of all the resources (img, javascript, css, etc.) that's loaded on a web page and filter it by file type and file size so I can see which resources need to be reduced.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Not with Javascript.  You would need some backend script like PHP or C# that can read the filesystem.

Comment: You can also use the Google Chrome Developer Tools (under the 'Network' tab) to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Network tab of Chrome's DevTools, install a browser extension such as Google's [Page Speed](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pagespeed-insights-by-goo/gplegfbjlmmehdoakndmohflojccocli) or Yahoo's [YSlow](http://yslow.org/) or use a web service like Google's [Page Speed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/) service or [Webpagetest](http://www.webpagetest.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers will have a dev toolkit where you can see resource sizes and load times. This should give you most of the information you need to optimize your site speeds and file sizes.